# How to put check boxes runtime in android

Tags: android

I have list of media files. When I play any media file it has to be checked automatically.
Is there any way to do this at runtime.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What about using the [`setChecked(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) method?

Comment: protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  
   
  String keyword = value[position];
  try
  {
   
      mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/sdcard/"+keyword+".mp4");

      mediaPlayer.prepare();
      mediaPlayer.start();   
      //keyword.setChecked(true);
   
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }


 }
this is my bit of code...I need to have check boxes when I call mediaPlayer.start() method

Comment: So... you except that I write the code, right? No way. Write it your self, test it, and come back with the problems you faced.